# npm i webpack -S command is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I am totally new to reactJS and nodeJS.
I am following [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack),
and finding error in this command `npm i webpack -S`.

[image: error]

Comment: Can you post some code? That will certainly help find the problem. LIke, the webpack config file, the html, and the component you've created

Comment: Check your proxy settings

Comment: I am just doing the basic installation through this tutorial https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack . I haven't write any html file yet

Comment: I dont know how to check my proxy settings

Comment: can you post your `package.json`? There seems to be an error in it.

Comment: {
  "name": "react-hello-world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "'",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "'"
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i got the answer thank you so much #MoeenMohsin ...........
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to specify proxy settings. You're under proxy and npm can't fetch package from it's repository. Your package.json looks good.

You can try something like this

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set http-proxy http://username:password@ip:port
npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@ip:port
npm set strict-ssl false
```

Thanks https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9401#issuecomment-134569585